# jQuery change css stylesheet based on element width

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create preview for mobile devices by using a simple switch, which dynamically loads and removes stylesheet from header:

```
$('.switch').on('click', function() {
    $('link[title="tablet"], link[title="phone"]').remove();
    var mode = $(this).data('mode');
    switch (mode) {
        case "screen":
            $("#main").css({width: '100%'});
            break;

        case "tablet":
            $("#main").css({width: '1024px'});
            $("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after('<link title="tablet" rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css" type="text/css">');
            break;

        case "phone":
            $("#main").animate({width: '768px'})
            $("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after('<link title="phone" rel="stylesheet" href="phone.css" type="text/css">');
            break;
    }
});
```

and here is simplified html:

```
<a class="action" data-mode="screen">Large</a>
<a class="action" data-mode="tablet">Medium</a>
<a class="action" data-mode="phone">Small</a>

<div id="main"></div>
```

The above partially works, all stylesheets are added/removed from 'header' as necessary, but the problem is that any combination of two works fine.

For example the default view is screen, so if I click on phone mode, that works fine, but if from phone mode I click on tablet mode, it does not work.

It only works whatever the second click is, be it phone or mobile, but in combination of all three I cant make it work.

In case if someone asks why not use responsive media queries, I dont want to resize window, the idea is for window to remain the same, but apply different stylesheet on main container width change.

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: You also can join your css-files into 1 and reorganize switching this way https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/knr0xvek/ . Or, if this not suitable for you, please provide complete example.